# Using mutex with NInject provider to prevent multi-threading concurrency access

Tags: multithreading, asp.net-mvc-4, ninject, mutex, ninject.web.mvc

In my Asp.Net MVC projects, I use NInject providers to create instances of UnitOfWork. (I use Mindscape.LightSpeed)

**Here is a sample of binding in my NinjectModule class:**

```
base.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().ToProvider(UnitOfWorkProvider<UnitOfWork>.CreateInstance(_lightSpeedContext, UnitOfWorkProvider.CreateUnitOfWork)).InRequestScope();
```

**And here is an example of what I'm doing in the provider to create instances:**

```
  protected override T CreateInstance(IContext context)
  {
     T unitOfWork = default(T);

     unitOfWork = this.CreateUnitOfWork();

     if (this.ConnectionStrategy != null)
        unitOfWork.ConnectionStrategy = this.ConnectionStrategy;

     return unitOfWork;
  }
```

**Should it be better to use mutex object like the example below?**

```
  private static readonly Mutex _mutex = new Mutex();

  protected override T CreateInstance(IContext context)
  {
     _mutex.WaitOne();

     try
     {
        T unitOfWork = default(T);

        unitOfWork = this.CreateUnitOfWork();

        if (this.ConnectionStrategy != null)
           unitOfWork.ConnectionStrategy = this.ConnectionStrategy;


        return unitOfWork;
     }
     finally
     {
        _mutex.ReleaseMutex();
     }
  }
```

I don't found any example of using mutex with Ninject provider on the Net and this is why I ask the question.

It would be nice to have an explanation of why mutex is or not good in the context of Asp.Net MVC.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use mutex, when you are declaring your `IUnitOfWork` in request scope?

It would be bottle-neck for your web application, because parallel requests will be waiting for another to create an instance of `IUnitOfWork`. Widely used practice is to create one instance of unit of work or database context (connection) etc. per web request (`IDisposable` objects will be disposed at the end of the request). Even if you declare your component `InSingletonScope`, Ninject should take care of concurrency issues.

Comment: The problem is: I must create my UnitOfWork with the help of a factory (the provider of NInject) because each instance of UnitOfWork is not just a 'new' instruction but instead a 'new' with a couple of assignments. A provider with NInject is in fact a Singleton because just one provider is assigned at the start of the application in the Global.asax. In this case, if the provider is a singleton, it will be asked to create one and only one instance per request but this instance will be created by the provider which is a Singleton. And if you have a Singleton, you have to deal with multi-thread.

Comment: OK, but in your example the provider is stateless. I don`t see any place, where race conditions could occur. If the method `CreateInstance` will be called from multiple threads simultaneously, each will get fresh instance of `IUnitOfWork`.

Comment: The 'base.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().ToProvider...' at the beginning of my example assign a singleton provider to create instances of IUnitOfWork. Each time a IUnitOfWork instance must be created, this singleton is called. This is the race conditions. I can be wrong?! What I understand is: If the provider is a singleton, it could be called my multiple threads at the same time. The function CreateInstance can therefore be corrupted. If it's not the case, I don't understand how threads works.

Comment: No it won't be corrupted if the method just creates new instances and holds no reference to some shared context - thread will just execute piece of code - if there is no shared piece of memory used by this code, then there is no problem. It could be problem if you for example read and increase some counter there.